# Disable DPAD keys in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-keypad

I am trying to catch events generated by the arrow keys (UP, DOWN, RIGHT and LEFT) and disable them. Below code snippet is from one of the activity class.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) return true;
    else return true;
}
```

However, with those code in place, key navigation is working. I tried adding key listener to activity which doesn't work either.

The target device is Samsung GT-I5500 with Android 2.2 version on.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I am not sure what returns event.getAction but maybe try to use if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN)

Comment: I tried that too! but not working.

Answer (score 7):

Override onKeyDown also and return true and not false.
Somnething like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, it hardly made any change. By the way, mine is a tabbed application using tabHost and TabGroupActivity. So is there anything I must taken care of?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyUp%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29), it is stated that you should return:

- *true* if you handled the event
- *false* if if you want to **allow the event to be handled by the next receiver**.

Your method is returning false, so you are passing the event to the default key handler

Comment: check the edit! I'm now returning true from the method. but keys are still enabled